# Combobox and Textbox with If Statement

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, c++-cli

I'm trying to have the textbox display a message when an item is selected on the combobox. However, nothing is happening. I tried SelectedItem and SelectedText and I get nothing in my text box, I even tried to hide one of the labels, again...nothing.

Here is the Code:

```
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this->comboBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->comboBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(41, 39);
        this->comboBox1->Name = L"comboBox1";
        this->comboBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(121, 21);
        this->comboBox1->TabIndex = 7;
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("300");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("1200");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("2400");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("9600");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("14400");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("19.2K");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("57.6K");
        this->comboBox1->Items->Add("115.2K");


private: System::Void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             if(comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString() == "300") 
             {
                 textBox1->Text= "Hello World?";
                 label1->Hide();
             }
         }
```

Comment: That looks like c++ to me...

Comment: Yes, this is a C++, I'm sorry, I shouldn't clicked the C# icon.

Comment: It is not C++, this is C++/CLI.  There's no sign that you actually subscribed the SelectedIndexChanged event.  So of course the event handler never runs.  This is very basic, at least read a tutorial on Winforms programming in C++/CLI.

Comment: Hey Hans, thank you for your suggestion and help, this will get me on the right track, this lead me to find a very good tutorial on Visual C++/CL.

Answer (score 2):

Try SelectedItem->Text. That's how you get the selected text for a ComboBox.

UPDATE: I googled a bit for you, and found this -- hope it helps!

http://www.programmersheaven.com/discussion/254711/getting-the-value-of-a-combobox

Comment: The compiler did not like that... gave me an error: 
error C2882: 'Text' : illegal use of namespace identifier in expression

Comment: Oops - I don't know C++, I just assumed the ComboBox in C++ would have the same properties as it does in C#.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, I agree with Hans I need to look into reading the tutorials on C++\CLI.